# File downloading from a specific URL is too slow

Tags: linux

I have to download a file named os161-binutils.tar.gz from a [URL](http://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs350/os161_repository/os161-binutils.tar.gz) by using ubuntu server version. I am using the command of `wget **URL**` but the speed is too slow i.e 2.8kb/s although my downloading speed normally ranges between 500-600 kb/s. what can be the possible solution for maximum downloading speed in this case ?

sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ubuntu and / or wget does not, in any way, affect the download speed of you file.

This could be however a server issue, the slowness could be related to an overload on the student.cs.uwaterloo.ca server, or simply because they have a slow upload speed.